# ANOVA: Should interactions always be tested if there are multiple independent variables (Effects)?

Tags: anova

I am attempting to determine if some of my independent variables have a significant effect on my response variables. In my case, I have various sites in which I determined the quantities of some antibiotic resistance genes (ARGs). So in this case my response variables is the quantities of ARGs and my effects are the river sites and ARG groups.

I have done some ANOVA on the samples and the effect between the two effect variables have been significant. I understand that if this is the case I cannot rely on the significant effect between individual independent variables and the response.

So my question is: Should the interactions between effect variables always be taken into account with multiple effect variables?

Answer (score 1):

"Always" is too strong and, given that there can be 3-way, 4-way etc. interactions, opens too big a set of tests for almost all cases. E.g. if you have 10 independent variables there are

1. 45 2-way and 8 way interactions
2. 120 3-way and 7 way interactions
3. 210 4-way and 6 way interactions
4. 252 5-way interactions

for a total of 1002 interactions.

Testing all of them would a) Require a ton of data and b) Probably yield an uninterpretable mess.

Test interactions if there is a theoretical reason to think they might be important or if there is substantive interest in the result.

Answer (score 0):

You innocent question opens the door to long and possibly divisive modelling-philosophical discussions. IMHO it depends on what your model is supposed to do (see [Shmueli 2010](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1294167961)).

Using an ANOVA implies (to me) that you are interested in testing a hypothesis about X1 and X2 affecting Y. Thus, I would expect your model to be motivated by theory. If said theory suggests an interaction, obviously you would put it in (and not ask the question). But additionally there are situations, where interactions should be considered (such as [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox)). Trouble is, you never know in advance. Still, I think it is defensible to *not* use interactions in hypothesis testing (and investigate them only *after* your main model, as part of the speculative outlook).

In explorative modelling mode (which personally I would not employ ANOVA for), the argument in favour of including interactions is stronger: if you don't really know the system that well, you don't want to use oversimplistic model structures. For example, in ecology or sociology the rule of thumb is "everything matters". Hence I would expect plenty of interactions in a model and question any explorative analysis that does not include them (same goes for non-linear effects, approximated by quadratic and possibly cubic model terms).